# the .xlsx file cannot readable by php

Tags: php, excel, codeigniter

I have a form that upload excel .xls format, it works fine but
when I try to change the allowed type to '.xlsx' I get the error :

The filename lalala.xlsx is not readable..

this is my controller :

```
function pesan()
    {
        $data= array( );
        if($this->input->post())
        {
            $email    =   $this->input->post('email');
            $config['upload_path'] = './kirim_undangan/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'xlsx';


            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            $this->load->library('session');
            $this->session->xls;
            $data = $_SESSION['xlsx'];

            if ( !isset ($this->session->xls))//session uniq id isset ?
            {
                $data = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

            }
            else
            {
                $data = array('error' => false);
                //$upload_data = $this->upload->data();

                $this->load->library('excel_reader');
                $this->excel_reader->setOutputEncoding('CP1251');

                $file =  FCPATH.'/kirim_undangan/' . $_SESSION['xlsx'] ; //pathnya file excel + uniqid + .xls
                $this->excel_reader->read($file);
                error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

                // Sheet 1
                $regex = "~\d{5}~";

                $data = $this->excel_reader->sheets[0] ;
                            $dataexcel = Array();
                for ($i = 1; $i <= $data['numRows']; $i++) 
                {

                    if($data['cells'][$i][1] == '') break;
                    $dataexcel[$i-1]['to_name'] = $data['cells'][$i][1];
                    $dataexcel[$i-1]['to_address'] = $data['cells'][$i][2];
                    $dataexcel[$i-1]['to_phone'] = $data['cells'][$i][3];
                    preg_match($regex, $data['cells'][$i][2] , $result);
                    $dataexcel[$i-1]['to_zipcode'] = $result[0];
                }

            $data_user = array(

                'request_Id'                    => $this->input->post('id'),
                'email'                         => $this->input->post('email'),
                'name'                          => $this->input->post('from_nama'),
                'phone'                         => $this->input->post('from_phone'),
                'status'                        => '0',
                'unique_id'                     => uniqid()


                );


            unlink(FCPATH.'/kirim_undangan/' . $_SESSION['xlsx']);
            $this->load->model('excel');
            $this->excel->tambahuser($dataexcel,$data_user);
            $data['msg'] = "Terima kasih ! Silahkan tunggu konfirmasi biaya melalui email !";

            }

        } 
        $this->load->view('index.php',$data);
    } 

    function upload() 
    {
        $this->load->library('session');

        if (!empty($_FILES)) 
        {
            $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
            $data = uniqid(). '.xlsx';
            $targetPath = getcwd() . '/kirim_undangan/';
            $targetFile = $targetPath . $data ;

            move_uploaded_file($tempFile, $targetFile);
            $_SESSION["xlsx"] = $data;
            print_r($_SESSION['xlsx']);
        }
    }
```

What is the best approach for my problem? Is there any way the CI library to recognize the xlsx file?

I have found that PHPExcel would fit to my issue, but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: Perhaps trying to read some of the [PHPExcel documentation](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/wiki/User%20Documentation) would help explain how to use it, or looking at some of the [examples](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/tree/1.8/Examples)

Comment: i have downloaded phpexcel.zip, which one should I put in the library folder? or all of them?

Comment: Everything in the `Classes` folder is the PHPExcel "library".... the other folders are documentation, examples, etc..... we try to give those folders sensible names, so that people can understand that documentation can be found in the folder called Documentation, etc